# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, adapter

I have created a activity and added a fragment to it, to that fragment I added gridview with images, when clicking on the image fragment should open but my fragment was not opening and getting crash and showing the above error.how to add fragments to the items of grid view

Screen //this fragment added to the main activity and have grid view with images

```
public class Screen extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;


    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Screen newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Screen fragment = new Screen();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public Screen() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen, container, false);
        int[] text = {R.string.temp, R.string.weight, R.string.len, R.string.time, R.string.area, R.string.vol, R.string.store, R.string.prsure, R.string.sound, R.string.ene, R.string.mag, R.string.img};
        int[] imgId = {R.drawable.temperature, R.drawable.food, R.drawable.resize, R.drawable.circular, R.drawable.pie, R.drawable.chemistry, R.drawable.database, R.drawable.blood, R.drawable.sound, R.drawable.energy, R.drawable.magnet, R.drawable.images};

        GridView grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        Custom_Grid adapter = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            adapter = new Custom_Grid(getContext(), text, imgId);
        }

        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Fragment fragment;
                FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new Temperature();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new Weight();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new Length();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        fragment = new Time();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        fragment = new Area();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid,fragment).commit();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        fragment = new Volume();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.grid,fragment).commit();
                        break;

                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }


}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

Fragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Screen scr = new Screen();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.sun,scr);
    ft.commit();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

logcat

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
03-10 05:58:23.188 24381-24381/com.example.cherrypandu.uc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:469)
03-10 05:58:23.188 24381-24381/com.example.cherrypandu.uc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)

```
    public class Custom_Grid extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;
    private final int[] text;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    public Custom_Grid(Context c, int[] text, int[] Imageid) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.text=text;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return text.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            textView.setText(text[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        return grid;
    }
```

grid_single:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="small text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:id="@+id/grid_text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have an element with named `one` in your XML layout?

Comment: yes, it is the layout of screen fragment which consists of gridview

Comment: @sun, post grid_single xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
fragment = new Temperature();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.one,fragment).commit();
break;
```

This is where it cannot find the view. Instead of **R.id.one** you should provide the id of the container where the fragments are added.

In your example, I think you should replace this with

```
fragment = new Temperature();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.CONTAINER_ID,fragment).commit();
break;
```

EDI***:Where CONTAINER_ID is exactly what it sounds like, the container for your fragments. Just declare it's id in xml.

Also beware of this part:

```
Custom_Grid adapter = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        adapter = new Custom_Grid(getContext(), text, imgId);
    }

    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If your build version doesn't meet this term, you might end up with a **NullPointerException**.

Comment: it getting unsupported operation exception.

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
03-10 05:58:23.188 24381-24381/com.example.cherrypandu.uc E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:469)
03-10 05:58:23.188 24381-24381/com.example.cherrypandu.uc E

Comment: Well that's a completely new error which you need to find and solve. I'm pretty sure that this fixed your original error.

Comment: Try and figure it out, if you cannot, post more details here. But I think that's a separate error.

Comment: Be sure to implement the edit, as @bryan_c suggested.

Answer (score 0):

in your xml layout define a FrameLayout as container for fragments and set an id for it.
then use this id in your switch experesion like this:

```
 case 0:
                    fragment = new Temperature();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayoutId,fragment).commit();
                    break;
```

Comment: that's almost the same as I said :)

Comment: you replaced GridView with a fragment that makes error . you must replace fragments with only fragments .

Comment: Well I said he should give the container id, which I thought was grid, but apparently not.

Comment: Ok my friend ,please edit your code and make it a better answer

Comment: means I have to take gridview and a frame layout in my Screen fragment by clicking items on gridview my all other fragments will open in frame layout  isn't it.

Comment: yes your other fragments will open in frame layout replace each other.